# How to build a dropdownmenu in flutter that doesn't follow the width of the maximum item's length in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In flutter, a `DropDownMenu`'s initial **view** (where it let us choose items) consists of the **width** of item having **longest length**. I want to give the `initial view` a **fixed** size.

But if I put `DropDownMenu` in a `container` with a `fixed width`, I get error like some amount of pixel over-followed.

Now how can I achieve a `DropDownMenu` whose width is fixed in flutter?

```
Container(
        width:75,
        child: DropdownButton(
          value: selectedItem,
          isExpanded: false,
          hint: Text("All"),
          onChanged: (selectedItem) {setState(() {
            this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
          });},
          underline: Text(""),
          isDense: true,
          onTap: () {},
          items: <String>["aaa", "bbb", "Item having the longest length", "Hello", "World", "good"].map((categoryName) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: categoryName,
            child: Text(
              categoryName
            ),
          )).toList(),
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `isExpanded` property to `true`:

```
DropdownButton(
    isExpanded: true,
)
```

and define a `TextOverflow` in the `Text` widget:

```
Text(
    categoryName,
    overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
)
```

Follows a full example:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        width: 155,
        child: DropdownButton(
          value: selectedItem,
          isExpanded: true,
          hint: Text("All"),
          onChanged: (selectedItem) {
            setState(() {
              this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
            });
          },
          underline: Text(""),
          isDense: true,
          onTap: () {},
          items: <String>[
            "aaa",
            "bbb",
            "Item having the longest length",
            "Hello",
            "World",
            "good"
          ]
              .map(
                (categoryName) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: categoryName,
                  child: Text(
                    categoryName,
                    overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                  ),
                ),
              )
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```